How to clean massage oil from cotton or linen towels
As a massage therapist I use a lot of massage oil to treat my customers, this oil does however get into my towels and clothes, causing a rancid smell that gets locked into the fabric. A regular wash doesn't clean this out. I have tried lots of different detergens already and am at my wits end. My knowledge of chemistry and textiles is insufficient to figure out what protocol and chemical agent to use to remove the oil from the textile. Does anybody know?

You may want to try dry cleaner service, but that can be expensive.

@Poutnik What protocol and chemical agents would they be using to get the fabrics oil free? I need to be able to do it myself ideally.

That is probably not feasible on your own, with health and fire hazards.

Anything you use will be flammable, and needs to be used in a well-ventilated environment to minimise your exposure. That said acetone or butanone may do what is needed

I think you should be more careful with oils to eliminate the problem.

Many dry-cleaners today generally use liquid or supercritical $\ce{CO2}$, which is, by and large, recycled.
If there is a laundromat nearby with a coin-operated $\ce{CO2}$ machine, you could do this yourself.
Avoid dry-cleaning using organic solvents, which may leave a lingering odor on towels.
{Note: So why is $\ce{CO2}$ not considered organic? Just a matter of definition.]
